# Has anyone heard of how .NET 4.0 may change/affect Asp.net MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

We should have a full release of asp.net MVC well before .NET 4.0 and VS 10 come out, right?

I'm really hoping MS can keep MVC as dynamic as other more open frameworks are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, MVC 1.0 RTM will ship as a fully supported Out-of-Band Framework before .NET 4.0 and VS 10 are released. We want to keep it dynamic as well and will continue to ship updates via CodePlex, as we did with 1.0. At least that's our current plan.

Comment: Pretty close to what I said, but good to hear an "official" answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it will have much impact, other than the fact that the MVC Framework will be part of the .NET Framework. The work being done on MVC should continue to be made available through CodePlex, even after the official release of both frameworks.